# How to break page on windows.print

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have one page where I had taken data list which get repeats.
The length of page get increase automatically on increasing of row data getting from database.

I have seen many links where there is code written for break down as

```
 table { page-break-inside:auto }
 tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
```

but is their any way that after some fix height the other additional records get print on other page.

Also if I try adding class in data list and in that class if I write logic for Break breakdown then that class will get repeat in Data list and so that each record will come in different page.

My issue is as

**Page-1**

[image]

**Page-2**

[image]

I need to implement logic for after fix height the additional records get printed on 2nd page.
**Can Some body can help me with same or with some different idea?**

Here I cannot measure what will be record that will bind in data list

And as shown in Image 1st page is blank and second page contains all the record coming in Data List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had simply added `<br/>` tag before `</asp:DataList>` some thing like below code and it started working for me.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" id="datalist">
<ItemTemplate>
//Repeat code
<br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```